# Compile sass (via compass) in RoR-environement without "compass watch"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

My current workflow is watching my SASS-files with `compass watch`. Works like a charm.

But if I work in Rails with only SASS (no COMPASS) running I can skip the whole watch thing. I just write pure SASS and it gets compiled. Easy. Is there a possibility to have it the same way with compass?

P.S.: I use a lot of compass mixins, so when running without `compass watch` it doesn't find the mixins and outputs errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing around a bit I actually found the solution :)

I removed the compiled files from COMPASS (the CSS files), didn't `compass watch` anymore and made sure that all my import routes were correct. The only files now in my stylesheet-folder are `.scss`.

Actually pretty simple and just the same as running SASS without COMPASS on rails. Just make sure you include the *compass-rails gem* in your gemfile :D